# Smallest angle between two curves

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

I was doing an exercise and I found out that the angle between two of my curves is is given by $$\arccos \left(\displaystyle\frac{3-4a^2}{5+4a^2}\right), \, a \in \mathbb{R}.$$

My question is, given whatever $a$, do I know for sure that this angle is the smallest? Cause we know the angle between two vectors (or curves) is defined as the smaller one.

In my case, does this expression always return the smallest value? If so,  why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not confuse the angle between lines with the angle between vectors. The latter can be any value between $0$ and $\pi$ - which is exactly the range of the $\arccos$ function. If you are interested in the smaller of two complementary angles just use absolute value of the argument instead.

Comment: Yes, it is the range, of course. I was missing that for some reason. Thank you.

Comment: Once more: the angle between two vectors is not "the smaller one". The angle is unique and unambiguous, there is no choice.

Comment: yes, but it is defined as the smallest angle. There are 4 angles (2 different angles that sum $\pi$)

Comment: No it is not. Either you have a bad teacher or you misunderstood him/her.

Comment: For example, the angle between vector $(1,0)$ and vector $(-1,\sqrt{3})$ is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, which is more than \frac{\pi}{2}.

Comment: As implicitly said in the first comment of @user, if you consider the angle of two non-oriented lines, you have an angle $\le \pi/2$ and another one $\ge  \pi/2$, but if the lines are oriented, angle$(L_1,L_2)$ is not ambiguous.

Comment: Oh its because of the orientation of the curves...of course! Thank you. I am also studying at home by myself..so...no teacher here...